# Optimise conversion to integer - pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 80,000 rows. One column 'prod_prom' contains either null values or string representations of numbers, i.e. including ','. I need to convert these to integers. So  far I have been doing this:

```
for row in DF.index:
    if pd.notnull(DF.loc[row, 'prod_prom']):
        DF.loc[row, 'prod_prom'] = int(''.join([char for char in DF.loc[row, 'prod_prom'] if char != ',']))
```

But it is extremely slow. Would it be quicker to do this in list comprehension, or with an apply function? What is best practice for this kind of operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand right, you have data like the following:

```
data = """
A,B
100,"5,000"
200,"10,000"
300,"100,000"
400,
500,"2,000"
"""
```

If that is the case probably the easiest thing is to use the `thousands` option in `read_csv` (the type will be `float` instead of `int` because of the missing value):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=True,thousands=',')

     A       B
0  100    5000
1  200   10000
2  300  100000
3  400     NaN
4  500    2000
```

If that is not an possible you can do something like the following:

```
print df

     A        B
0  100    5,000
1  200   10,000
2  300  100,000
3  400      NaN
4  500    2,000

df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace(r',','').astype(float)
print df

    A       B
0  100    5000
1  200   10000
2  300  100000
3  400     NaN
4  500    200
```

I changed the type to float because there are no `NaN` integers in pandas.

Comment: Importing with thousands works nicely, I worry (probably for no good reason) that it might make a mess of my other coloumns (as I have not taken time to confirm the presence of ',' values in other string columns. The second solution seems better for me in that case. presumably I could combine that technique in some sort of list comprehension to get both ints and NA values. Thanks

Comment: Can you specify which columns to import with the thousands option?

Comment: The NaN should be handled automatically by `pandas`. You shouldn't have to worry about them at all. And even if you change the individual elements to `int` in a list comprehension because you have NaN values in some elements pandas will automatically change the dtype of the column to `float`

Comment: when i use thousdands it cannot convert '4, 453.80'. Is that typical?

Comment: Yes, because of the space after the comma. With no space it should convert fine.